# Java issue with message for PrintWriter

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to put this which worked in a jsp file into a PrintWriter.

From:

```
<td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${al.base64Image}" width="240" height="300"/></td>
```

To:

```
out.print("<td>" +"<img src=data:image/jpg;base64," + al.getBase64Image()+ "width='240' height='300'/></td>");
```

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: Image is empty as if was not found the src..

Comment: Where was it coming from originally?

Comment: From mysql database.. In jsp works, so I think there is no problem with encoding part

Comment: Well, you're certainly not writing out the same thing--the `src` property needs to be quoted (as in your JSP), you should put a space before the `width` property declaration, etc. At least get the markup right, *then* worry about anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing out the markup you need to wrap the base64 encoded src attribute in a either a `'` or a `"` (Which would be inserted into you string as an escaped quote `\"`). Also note that you are missing a space before the width property.

```
out.print("<td><img src='data:image/jpg;base64," + al.getBase64Image()+ "' width='240' height='300'/></td>");
```

You can always test the validity of your markup using the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)